# How do I increase the gap between a UITableView section headerview and first cell?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview, swift

I added a UISegmentedControl as my headerview for a section. Now the top part of my first first tableView cell is being cut off as shown in image.

[image]

Is there a way to fix this?

I've try messing with tableView insets and scrollView but had zero luck.

In my viewDidLayoutSubviews I cancelling out the height fixes it:

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    var frame = segmentedControl.frame
    frame.size.height = 29.0
    segmentedControl.frame = frame
    segmentedControl.tintColor = ColourHelper().segmentedControlRed
    segmentedControl.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex = 1
    segmentedControl.addTarget(self, action: "segmentedControlTapped:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)
    tableView.headerViewForSection(1)?.hidden = true
}
```

But now my UISegmentedControl's height doesn't match the rest of my segmented controls in my app.

[image]

Comment: Sounds like you're not specifying the correct height for the header

Comment: (What does heightForHeaderInSection return?)

Comment: @HotLicks I didn't even set it. But setting it fixed my issue. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't need to set the frame manually like shown in my question. I removed that code:

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    segmentedControl.tintColor = ColourHelper().segmentedControlRed
    segmentedControl.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex = 1
    segmentedControl.addTarget(self, action: "segmentedControlTapped:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)
    tableView.headerViewForSection(1)?.removeFromSuperview()

}
```

Then set the height of the header like so:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 29.0
}
```